# How to exaggerate values in range [0;2]?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, exponential-function

For values `x` in range `[0;2]` I need a function `y=f(x)` which maps the values to a larger range `[0;L]` exaggerating the distances between values. One such example is a polynomial: `y=x**3` (gives `L=8`). I would like to have exponential exaggeration, but AFAIK the exponential function rather slows down in range `[0;1]`. Perhaps this has something to do with derivatives, but I'm not sure how to formulate "exaggeration" in strict mathematical terms.

**Clarification 1**: In the other words, I would like `f(x)` to grow in range `[0;2]` like e.g. `2**x` grows in range `1...log2(L)` .

**Clarification 2**: The problem with `y=kx` is that distances stay proportional to initial distances. For `x1<x2<x3` from `[0;2]` I would like to get `y1<<y2<<y3`, like `1<2<3` yields `2<<4<<8` for `y=2**x`.

Comment: Try $y=e^{ax}-1$ and adjust $a$ however you want.

Comment: @Serge Are you able to describe what you mean by "exponential exaggeration"?  Essentially, the derivative of $f$ controls the exaggeration factor in any vicinity.  Naturally it is possible to make some parts of $[0,2]$ have larger derivatives than others, but what would "exponential" mean in this context?  In particular, the inputs are bounded in $[0,2]$ so pretty much any increasing function could be said to grow exponentially on such a short domain.

Comment: @ErickWong , I've tried to clarify in the question.

Comment: You could try $f(x)=\frac{-1}{a(x-2)}$, and adjust $a$. This lets you have $f(0)$ arbitrarily close to $0$ but $f(2)$ arbitrarily large (and its also easy to compute).